# Vaadin in Eclipse Luna IvyDE resolve

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin, ivyde

Is IvyDE resolve supposed to run every time a new vaading project is created? Or is there a way have dependencies configured globally for all projects.It takes a long time to resolve and sometimes gives an error.
I am using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 with Vaadin plugin 7. I am a newbie to Eclipse IDE and Vaadin.

Answer (score 0):

Ivy stores resolved dependencies to a local repository, which means that those are downloaded only once. Standard location for the directory containing resolved dependencies is `~/.ivy2`.

Comment: But every time I start a new project it starts resolving and it takes hours!

Comment: Do you use the same Vaadin version every time?

Comment: <!ENTITY vaadin.version "7.3.10">
Yes sir. It was completely resolved once. But now it gives errors upon resolving.

Comment: The error I'm getting is a download error. My download sizes are limited by network. But it was all resolved successfully when the first project was created.

Comment: Have you tried to clear the project or even tried to download the 7.3.9 and check if it works?

Comment: I tried Vaadin with IntelliJ Idea 13.1.4. and it works fine! Guess the problem was with my Eclipse instance.